# neo4j v2.2.0 default password not working?

Tags: neo4j, passwords

I recently upgraded from Neo4j v.2.1.7 to v.2.2.0

However, the default username/password (neo4j/neo4j) is not being recognized.

How is this resolved?

Comment: it can also be a browser caching issue, try shift reload

Comment: On a fresh install of neo4j-community-2.2.4 I get the message "Invalid username or password." when submitting the login form at http://localhost:7474/browser/ with the default username neo4j and password neo4j. I did enable org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0 and dbms.security.auth_enabled=true with a server stop and start and a browser shift-reload.

Comment: I then changed the property org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=127.0.0.1 to match my /etc/hosts and tried on http://127.0.0.1:7474/browser/ but got the same message.

Comment: Sorry for the thread hijack. I now posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666453/cannot-log-in-neo4j-server

Answer (score 8):

Do you need authentication? If not you could turn it off by setting

```
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```

in neo4j-server.properties. This is a new config line added in Neo4j 2.2. If found in a fresh installation it would look like this:

```
# Require (or disable the requirement of) auth to access Neo4j
dbms.security.auth_enabled=true
```

When upgrading the line may not be present - if not it can be added in safely.

Comment: Thanks, ceej.  The only issue is that line is not found in my neo4j-server.properties file.

Comment: That's no problem. If you upgraded then it won't be - authN was added in Neo4j 2.2. Simply add it and you will be good to go. I've edited my answer slightly to be clearer.

Comment: Glad to help! I admit I do not know why the default username/password is not working.