# Windows neo4j: Cannot login / connect to database / browser

Tags: .net, api, neo4j

I've just installed neo4j desktop 5.6.0 (which I'm going to use in a dotnet 7 API), but no matter what I try, my login / password is always refused.

I didn't make any changes to default config, so username/password should be neo4j/neo4j, but they obviously doesn't work.

if I open browser URL via:

```
http://localhost:7474/browser/
```

and try to connect using bolt via:

```
bolt://localhost:7687
```

I always get

> Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.

Running

```
.\neo4j.bat start
```

via a PowerShell Windows console:

Pops up a "Apache Commons Daemon Service Runner" asking for confirmation, and after I hit "Yes" it returns:

```
Started neo4j. It is available at http://localhost:7474
There may be a short delay until the server is ready.
```

But then

```
.\neo4j.bat status --verbose
```

returns:

```
neo4j 5.3.0
VM Name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
VM Vendor: Oracle Corporation
VM Version: 17.0.6+9-LTS-190
JIT compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
VM Arguments: [-Dbasedir=C:\Users\diego.estebanperez_a\.Neo4jDesktop\relate-data\dbmss\dbms-7b389a4d-222f-44d9-b8f1-dca7064ee5a9]
Configuration files used (ordered by priority):
C:\Users\diego.estebanperez_a\.Neo4jDesktop\relate-data\dbmss\dbms-7b389a4d-222f-44d9-b8f1-dca7064ee5a9\conf\neo4j.conf
--------------------
Executing command line: powershell.exe -OutputFormat Text -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Get-Service neo4j | Format-Table -AutoSize
org.neo4j.cli.CommandFailedException: Neo4j is not running.
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Bootloader$Dbms.status(Bootloader.java:479)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.StatusCommand.execute(StatusCommand.java:37)
        at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:92)
        at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:37)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1953)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1300(CommandLine.java:145)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2358)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2352)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2314)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2179)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2316)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2078)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jAdminCommand.call(Neo4jAdminCommand.java:122)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jAdminCommand.call(Neo4jAdminCommand.java:42)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1953)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1300(CommandLine.java:145)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2358)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2352)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2314)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2179)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2316)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2078)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jCommand.main(Neo4jCommand.java:41)
```

Of course I tried to use it in a .net api registering the neo4j client like this (neo4jclient Nuget previously installed):

```
var client = new BoltGraphClient(new Uri("bolt://localhost:"), "neo4j", "neo4j");
client.ConnectAsync();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IGraphClient>(client);
```

To no avail too.

I've also installed the service via:

```
.\neo4j.bat windows-service install
```

And also tried setting an initial password via:

```
./neo4j-admin dbms set-initial-password root
```

To no avail too.

What can I try next?

PS. Already investigated and tried some links like

[Cannot log in Neo4j server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666453/cannot-log-in-neo4j-server)

Comment: I do not think neo4j 5.6.0 is available yet. Where did you find it?

Comment: Hi @cybersam. "dotnet add package Neo4j.Driver --version 5.6.0" (https://www.nuget.org/packages/neo4j.driver) and "dotnet add package Neo4jClient --version 5.1.6" (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Neo4jClient)

Comment: OK. You are using 5.6.0 of the _dotnet driver_, but you are actually using version 5.3.0 of the server (as I see later on in your question). So your first sentence should have said "driver" instead of "desktop" (which has its own version number as well). Actually, you don't even need to mention the driver at all, since you cannot log in on the Browser -- I think your question needs to focus on that, unless you don't really care about using the Browser.

Comment: Thanks for your input @cybersam, you are completely right. I'm new to neo4j and was investigating, but in the end I will use it in a dotnet api, so I only need the dotnet nuget neo4jclient package, and not neo4j driver at all. Now I was able to solve the auth problem, it was about myself missunderstanding the basic concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically when using Neo4j Desktop the initial database password is set via the Neo4j Desktop UI:

[image]

So whatever text you use here will be the initial password for the `neo4j` database user.

Also, note that the default minimum password length is 8 characters so it is possible your attempts to set an initial password with fewer characters was ignored if the password is less than the minimum number of characters. More information in the docs here: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/set-initial-password/

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply @William Lyon. I installed (and reinstalled) neo4j desktop several times, and I was never asked to enter an initial password, and when I tried to change it through the shell I was adviced to use more than 8 characters and did so to no avail.

Comment: I have to add I'm new to neo4j, and when installed neo4j desktop only an example project with "Movie DBMS" database is created. Now I realized that I have to create a new project and assign a database and a password and start the database. Now it works, and you put me in the right direction, so thanks!